# Better method to assign values to variables

Tags: c, optimization

So I'm currently writing some code that will output a string, created based on the state of bits in a variable. Currently my code looks something along these lines

```
uint8_t importantVariable;

if(BIT0&importantVariable){
    valA = 'A';
else{
    valA = 'B';
}
if(BIT1&importantVariable){
    valB = 'A';
else{
    valB = 'B';
}
if(BIT2&importantVariable){
    valC = 'A';
else{
    valC = 'B';
}

printf(examplestring, "valA is %c, valB is %c, valC is %c",ValA,ValB,ValC);
```

This seems like a very clunky way to accomplish this however and I was wondering if there was a shorter method that could accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make an array with the possible values for each bit, and use a combination of shifts and masks to obtain the proper value.

Here is an example:

```
// Rather than defining a mask, say, 0x04, define the number of right shifts
// for the corresponding bit to get into the LSB position:
#define BIT3_SHIFT 2

static char bit3_values[] = {'A', 'B'};
...
valA = bit3_values[(importantVariable >> BIT3_SHIFT) & 1];
```

This approach lets you move the target values into array initializers, so that they are no longer part of the code. It also eliminates conditional execution.

It also lets you act on combinations of several consecutive bits. For example, if you would like to assign one of four values based on the combination of bits 6 and 7, you can define a four-element array of values, shift your `importantVariable` by 6, and mask with `0x03` before indexing into the array of values.

Answer (score 2):

There's a shorter way, not an opmitization though...

Use the ternary operator:

```
valA = BIT0&importantVariable ? 'A' : 'B';
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility to avoid the `else`s.

```
char valA = 'B';
char valB = 'B';
char valC = 'B';

if(BIT0&importantVariable)
    valA = 'A';
if(BIT1&importantVariable)
    valA = 'A';
if(BIT2&importantVariable)
    valA = 'A';
```

Although I'd prefer the ternary operator (that I've +1'd).

Answer (score 1):

Asuming the statement (BITx&importantVariable) will always return 0 or 1 you could also use:

> valx = 'B' - (BITx&importantVariable);

Answer (score 0):

If the relevant bits are consecutive bits then you could do something more generic:

```
char values[3] = { 0 };
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    int bit = 1 << i;
    values[i] = bit & importantVariable;
}
printf(examplestring, "valA is %c, valB is %c, valC is %c", values[0], values[1], values[2]);
```